# Is "pay per click" really effective?

Tags: google-adsense

I visit many sites but click on their ads very rarely. I suppose many people do the same thing.

Do you think that publishing an article under "pay per click" policy, can have good earnings?

Comment: This should be community wiki since there's no clear-cut answer. I mean, since the PPC industry exists and is thriving, obviously there are many people making money on PPC. So if you're looking for opinions on the value of PPC, then this needs to be community wiki.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a yes/no answer to your question. From my experience:

- AdWords could make sense. You have to be really careful when crafting your message and when crafting the landing page. It's really important that you don't mislead the visitor that he/she'll find something that he won't. Just like you, I personally don't click paid campaigns, however many people who are on the look for a solution, do. If AdWords campaigns are well optimized, they can guarantee you a conversion rate (purchase) similar to the one that comes from organic search (which along with direct traffic, is usually the most qualified traffic).
- AdSense is a different story, I think. Google is in charge with "deciding" on which site of its advertising network it will have your ad displayed, which leaves control out of your hands. There is an option to specify the exact websites on which Google will display your ad, however, it's much more expensive - I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I'm guessing he means whether _selling_ PPC advertising is worthwhile. Otherwise it doesn't make sense to raise the issue of low click-thru rates since by definition of PPC, you're guaranteed X number of clicks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, do you mean spending money on adsense campaigns, or actually putting adsense campaigns on your website? (or something different again?)

My experience - one of the websites I help out with (selling car parts) spends money on adwords campaigns desipte doing well in organic rankings, we have trialled abandoning adwords and traffic/takings went down, so we continue paying for the meantime.